# Why can't I define a bit in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Why isn't there a bit structure in C#?

Comment: There is support for this now in c# 7.0....albeit 11 years later :) I added the answer below.

Answer (score 21):

For what's worth, here is a full-fledged bit structure, complete with `int` and `bool` casting and arithmetic operations. Probably not perfect, but works fine for me. Enjoy!

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a single bit that can be implicitly cast to/from and compared
/// with booleans and integers.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// An instance with a value of one is equal to any non-zero integer and is true,
/// an instance with a value of zero is equal to the integer zero and is false.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// Arithmetic and logical AND, OR and NOT, as well as arithmetic XOR, are supported.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public struct Bit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance with the specified value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public Bit(int value) : this()
    {
        Value = value == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of the bit, 0 or 1.
    /// </summary>
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    #region Implicit conversions

    public static implicit operator Bit(int value)
    {
        return new Bit(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Bit value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Bit value)
    {
        return value.Value == 1;
    }

    public static implicit operator Bit(bool value)
    {
        return new Bit(value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Arithmetic operators

    public static Bit operator |(Bit value1, Bit value2)
    {
        return value1.Value | value2.Value;
    }

    public static Bit operator &(Bit value1, Bit value2)
    {
        return value1.Value & value2.Value;
    }

    public static Bit operator ^(Bit value1, Bit value2)
    {
        return value1.Value ^ value2.Value;
    }

    public static Bit operator ~(Bit value)
    {
        return new Bit(value.Value ^ 1);
    }

    public static Bit operator !(Bit value)
    {
        return ~value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region The true and false operators

    public static bool operator true(Bit value)
    {
        return value.Value == 1;
    }

    public static bool operator false(Bit value)
    {
        return value.Value == 0;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Comparison operators

    public static bool operator ==(Bit bitValue, int intValue)
    {
        return 
          (bitValue.Value == 0 && intValue == 0) || 
          (bitValue.Value == 1 && intValue != 0);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Bit bitValue, int intValue)
    {
        return !(bitValue == intValue);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is int)
            return this == (int)obj;
        else
            return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This does not use 1bit of memory though, it uses 4 bytes, because all you're doing is wrapping around an int.

Comment: I never claimed that this _uses_ 1 bit of memory. It just _represents_ 1 bit. I still don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: I read the question as implying why one isn't built in natively.  Perhaps that's why some are downvoting?

Comment: The answer is that bits never occur in isolation and it's very inefficient to maintain named bit indices.  Bits will always be contained by numeric primitives where you have full access to the individual bits and a full range of bit-wise operators.

Comment: @RickO'Shea 1) Bits _do_ appear in isolation in some contexts, for example when representing individual microprocessor flags in emulators. 2) I just posted a class that is useful for me with the hope that it might be useful to someone else, it's up to you to decide whether it suits your needs (in terms or efficiency, and/or otherwise) or not.

Answer (score 18):

It is called a boolean.  At least, it would serve the basic function, right?  You don't twiddle bits that often in C# (at least, I don't), and if you need to you can use the built in operations.

Comment: Booleans are generally not one bit in size.

Comment: True, their size is implementation defined.  Doesn't mean that it can't serve the same purpose.

Comment: @JasperBekkers Well, you can't really handle single bits in memory anyway. There's issues of memory alignment and padding. True, if you have many bits, you can represent them efficiently, but that's what `BitArray` is for.

Comment: @Luaan You're correct that most hardware doesn't load/store individual bits like that - however you can still have information represented by a single bit. Or pack many bits together. And although booleans represent only a single bit of information, their physical size isn't.

Comment: @JasperBekkers: But you cannot individually address single bits in memory, but is why the space concern is invalid.

Comment: @EdS. Of course you can't, but if you have more than one of them the space /does/ count :) Rarely any problem ever is of size 1.

Comment: @JasperBekkers: Of course.  I answered this question quite some time ago when I was just starting to play around with C#.  I wouldn't answer it this way today.

Answer (score 15):

There **is** a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class..

Answer (score 10):

What would you want to do with it? Bear in mind that the CLR isn't going to try to pack multiple variables into a byte, so having one on its own would be no more useful than boolean. If you wanted to have a collection of them - well, that's what [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) is for, as David pointed out.

If we *did* have a Bit structure, I suspect people would expect multiple Bit variables to be packed efficiently in memory - by not having the type in the first place, we avoid that expectation and lead people towards other solutions such as BitArray.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a collection of bit flags, then using enums (with falgs attribute) and integers work a long way.

Answer (score 3):

Along with the BitArray class already mentioned there is a also the more efficient [BitVector32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx).

> BitVector32 is more efficient than BitArray for Boolean values and
>   small integers that are used internally. A BitArray can grow
>   indefinitely as needed, but it has the memory and performance overhead
>   that a class instance requires. In contrast, a BitVector32 uses only
>   32 bits.

Keep in mind you are limited to 32 values.

[Examples of BitVector32 usage at Dotnetpearls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/bitvector32)

Answer (score 2):

Though maybe there are rare exceptions, computers are not designed or intended to manipulate or allocate individual bits. Even at the lowest levels (assembly or pure machine language), you will not be able to allocate or access an individual bit. You have the same tools available in this regard as you have from any programming level: bytes and bitwise operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this now in C# 7.0!

public const int One =  0b0001;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#numeric-literal-syntax-improvements

Comment: Binary numeric literals are completely unrelated to a bit data-type, which is what this question is asking.